# Piping output to tee breaks the conditional

Tags: shell, pipe, tee

I am trying to test for the presence of custom firewall-rules on servers. I am doing this by processing the iptables output with awk and returning an appropriate exit-code. This works as intended, and the correct result is printed. However, when this is piped into tee, the conditional no longer works, and the result is printed every time.

```
# The broken code
ssh server1 'sudo iptables -L | awk "(!/ACCEPT/ && !/^target/ && !/^$/) {rules=1 ;} (rules==1) {exit 1}" && printf "%s\n" "string1" "string2" | sudo tee -a /path/to/file'
```

```
# The same code without `| sudo tee -a /path/to/file` works as intended
ssh server1 'sudo iptables -L | awk "(!/ACCEPT/ && !/^target/ && !/^$/) {rules=1 ;} (rules==1) {exit 1}" && printf "%s\n" "string1" "string2"'
```

What am I missing? I'm using GNU coretils 8.30 and GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1) on RHEL8. I've just noticed the awk statement could be shortened, but that's not the point :D

Comment: Are you sure it's not `awk`'s output that is piped to `tee` in your actual code, rather than `printf`'s?

Comment: exactly, the first one has `iptables | awk && printf | tee`, so the tee looks to be outside the conditional, only seeing the output of `printf`. That shouldn't affect if `
printf` runs

Comment: Also `ssh server1 server2` would run the `server2` command on the `server1` host. Please make sure the code you give in your question is representative of the actual command you ran.

Comment: Note that none of `ssh`, `awk`, `sudo` are from GNU coreutils. Only `tee` there is.

Comment: Beware that `iptables -L` only dumps rules in the `filter` table (not those in the `mangle`, `raw`, `nat`... ones for instance) and several systems have switched to `nft` already.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, the printf statements are piped to tee. You're quite right; the server1 server2 syntax wasn't original and I've adjusted the snippet accordingly. Thanks for the advice regarding the other tables.

Comment: @ilkkachu I wouldn't expect the presence of a pipe to affect the control flow preceding the previous command either, but it appears to. The working code prints the two lines depending on the exit status of the awk statement. The same working code with the pipeline on the end prints the two lines every time... I'm at a loss as to why.

Comment: Try running with `set -o xtrace` added at the beginning of the remote code. Also try with a simpler version like `false && echo test | tee -a /dev/null`

Comment: Try it as `iptables | (awk && printf) | tee`  (i.e. run awk and printf as a grouped command in a subshell) or `iptables | { awk && printf; } | tee` (the semi-colon and the space after `{` are required) as a grouped command in the same shell.  See `man bash` and search for the `Compound Commands` section.  or read https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html

Comment: Easier method: Write a `bash` script locally that does what you want. Be sure the script is executable (`chmod +x the_script`). Then, a 3 step procedure: `scp the_script root@server1`, `ssh root@server1 'bash  ./the_script' |&:tee server1.log`, `ssh server1 rm the_script`.Explained in `man ssh ssh-add scp ssh-copy-id ssh-keygen`

Answer (score -1):

Your complaint centers around what status that `iptables ... | awk ... && printf ... | tee ...`
pipeline returns.
The bash [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)
explains what its value will be.

> The return status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command, unless the pipefail option is enabled. If pipefail is enabled, the pipeline's return status is the value of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands exit successfully.

Consider executing

```
set -o pipefail
```

before piping results.

Alternatively, use the `... | (cmd ... || true) | ...` idiom
so each of the stages will return `0`,
if you find that simpler.
Emit a distinctive message upon detecting an exceptional case,
so a later pipeline stage can `grep` for it.

The design decision to have bash conditionally coordinate
awk's simple processing and printf's simple processing
maybe made sense at the time, but now you find it a drag
on productivity. Consider combining that logic into a
single, simple awk script.

---

You might find it more convenient to run shorter pipelines.

```
ssh server1 ... | awk ...  > server1.txt
# awk exit status is now available in $? so you can conditionally run printf

cat server1.txt  >> /path/to/file
```

---

In the original question /path/to/file is a server pathname,
and we're running a one-liner remote pipeline of some complexity.
You might find it more convenient to bring the raw `iptables -L`
output back across the ssh connection, and run a local pipeline.
Having produced a local results file, you can always store it with:

```
cat results.txt | ssh server1 'cat >> /path/to/file'
```